# Is my example enough for the question below, CFG, Please Help

Tags: examples-counterexamples, context-free-grammar

Is my example enough for the question below:

$Question:$

Give a counterexample to show that the following construction fails to prove that
the class of context-free languages is closed under star. Let $A$ be a $CFL$ that is
generated by the $CFG$ $G = (V,\sum,R, S)$. Add the new rule $S \Rightarrow  SS$ and call the resulting grammar $G'$. This grammar is supposed to generate $A$*.

$My\ Example:$

Suppose the context-free language A , and the corresponding grammar is
$G = \{\{S\} , \{( , )\} , \{S\Rightarrow (S), S \Rightarrow \epsilon\}, S\}$. Then if we add $S \Rightarrow SS$ and get the new grammar $G'$,
the language generated by G' will have $(()())$ , which is not contained in $A$* . Hence, the new grammar does not generate $A$* in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is OK. However I would add a little explanation why $(()())$ is not in $A^*$, to show you understand, and are not bluffing. But indeed your solution demonstrates that the problem is that $S\to SS$ must only be applied on the top-level and not "deeper" inside derivations. Usually that is enforced by having a new axiom.

Tiny note. I am accustomed to write $\to$ for rules (=productions) and $\Rightarrow$ for derivation steps.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is right.

To ensure you are producing A*, you should add a new start symbol, let s say X and add the rules:

X → XS | epsilon

Answer (score 0):

Since A* must contains the empty string, If A has no empty string
(the derivation "S-> ϵ" not in the set of productions of the grammar generates A), then the derivation "S->SS" generates no empty String, though A* must have ϵ -><-